# invalid property value for padding

Tags: css, ruby, html

I am getting invalid property value for padding and I don't know why. This code is written in ruby btw. When I check with the browser it has the right value pixels, however it is crossed out w a line and it isn't reading that attribute. Thanks in advance.

```
<% mywaldo = Mapping::MYWALDOS.sample %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sinatra Single-Serve</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
      div {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 768px;
        background-image: url("img/waldos/<%= mywaldo[0]%>") ;
      }
      #waldo {
        position:absolute;
        top: <%= mywaldo[2]%>;
        left: <%= mywaldo[1]%>;
        padding: <%= mywaldo[3]%>, <%= mywaldo[4]%>;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a id="waldo" href="">AA</a>
    </div>
    <%= yield %> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There should not be a comma between your values:

```
    padding: <%= mywaldo[3]%> <%= mywaldo[4]%>;
```